# When building a Python package, is there a way to include files/folders in the source distribution, but not the wheel

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-packaging

I have a dependency that's part of the build step for my project ([pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv)). Code from that package needs to run prior to `setup.py`. For that reason, I've included it as part of my package within a `vendor` folder.

I'm aware that having that package in `install_requires` would include it in the source distribution, but not the wheel. The reason I can't do that is because that package is required to parse the information that makes up `install_requires`.

Is there any way to include arbitrary files and folders as part of a source distribution, but not the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `installed_requires`? Do you mean [install_requires](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords)? In that case you are completely wrong, that keyword doesn't put anything in source dist (or wheels), it specifies what other distributions need to be installed with this one.

File `MANIFEST.in` controls what go into sdist. Read https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/#using-manifest-in

Comment: You're right, I meant `install_requires`. I misunderstood `MANIFEST.in`. Turns out, that's exactly what I needed.